# Problema com retorno do método fetch_all da classe MySQLi do PHP

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, mysqli

Então, eu estou fazendo a manutenção de um sistema muito grande. Tenho a query:

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT*FROM tabela");
```

E o problema é que utilizaram `fetch_all()` para retornar os dados. Quando a query não retorna registros o método `fetch_all()` não é definido na classe `mysqli_result`. Portando quando a query não retorna registros e eu tento chamá-lo, tenho o warning de método indefinido.

Já cheguei a fazer algo do tipo:

```
$resultado = $query->num_rows > 0 ? $query->fetch_all() : array();
```

isto faz com que `$resultado` vire um array em branco se a query não possuir registros retornados. o problema é que são muitas linhas de código que deverão ser editadas. Há alguma forma de "criar" este método `fetch_all()` no objeto e fazê-lo retornar um array em branco se a query não retornar registros? (mesmo ou qualquer outra alternativa).

**@Edit**

Descobri que falta o `mysqlnd`. Mas a pergunta segue: como fazer o `fetch_all()` ser chamado mesmo que ele não exista?

Grato

Comment: O `fetch_all()`  não vai funcionar se a consulta tiver algum erro, se não tiver nada ele funciona normal porém não retornar registros.

Comment: Obrigado. Procurei o porquê de estar dando erro e é porque falta o mysqlnd no servidor. Vou editar a pergunta.

Comment: Trocar o `fetch_all()` por `fetch_array()` é muito complicado?

Comment: Nesta situação sim, pois milhares de linhas deverão ser alteradas. :/

Comment: Como assim? tem muitas chamadas de `fetch_all()`?

Comment: Exatamente isso.

Comment: E pedir para hospedagem instalar o mysqlnd é possível?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui da seguinte forma:

```
<?php

class MySQLiConnector extends \mysqli
{
    function __construct($host, $user, $pass, $db)
    {
        parent::__construct($host, $user, $pass, $db);
    }

    public function query($query) {
        if( !$this->real_query($query) ) {
            throw new exception( $this->error, $this->errno );
        }

        return new MySQLiResultSet($this);
    }
}

class MySQLiResultSet extends \MySQLi_Result
{
    public function fetch()
    {
        return $this->fetch_assoc();
    }

    public function fetch_all()
    {
        $rows = array();
        while($row = $this->fetch())
        {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        return $rows;
    }
}
```

e passei a instanciar minha classe MySQLiConnector em vez de mysqli no meu objeto de conexão.